# "On the underground" vs "in the underground"

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct?

> I travel **on** the underground/subway to work.
>
> I travel **in** the underground/subway to work.

I'd choose the first option as we say *on a bus/tram/street car*.

Comment: related: [on a project vs in a project](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/on-a-project-vs-in-a-project)

Comment: related: [on orbit vs in orbit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/in-orbit-vs-on-orbit)

Comment: related: [Is there a connection between the various “states of being” that you can be “on”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27210/is-there-a-connection-between-the-various-states-of-being-that-you-can-be-on)

Comment: related: [Why “step into a car” but “step onto a plane”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55948/why-step-into-a-car-but-step-onto-a-plane)

Comment: You already seem to know which one you want to use. I don't see any value in this question, it's not usefully different from the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *by* with most forms of transport. You can say you’re going *by* land, *by* air, *by* sea, *by* car, *by* train, *by* ship, and *by* underground. You can also travel, or be, *on* a train, *on* a bus, *on* a tram and *on* the underground (note the change of article). You cannot, however, normally travel, or be, *on* a car.

(*In* and *on*, and also *by*, are not articles, but prepositions.)

Comment: NGram says we Brits go *on the underground* twice as often as *by the underground*. Or we go *by tube*.

Comment: All the above, but *under the boardwalk*. :-)