# "On Mac OS X" vs. "in Mac OS X"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, computing, in-on

The NY Times uses both "on Mac OS X" and "in Mac OS X". Can someone explain which one seems more appropriate if there is no difference?

Comment: Can you be more specific? The preposition choice highly depends on the sentence and, more specifically, on the verb used. If you ask for a certain verb, it'd be easier to answer. Related (not sure if they are dupes yet): [“on a project” vs “in a project”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5881), [“in orbit” vs. “on orbit”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5320)

Answer (score 6):

To me, at least, "on Mac OS X" refers to things that run on top of Mac OS X, while "in Mac OS X" refers to things that are part of Mac OS X.

Comment: +1.  On Mac OS, MS Word does such-and-such.  In Mac OS, memory is managed by thus-and-such.

Answer (score 3):

In computer terminology, "on" typically refers to things that involve a "platform":

> I sell my music **on** Amazon.
>
> My website is **on** the World Wide Web.

"In" will refer to specific programs, stores or components:

> I sell my music **in** the iTunes store.
>
> To open a file **in** Excel...

The confusion around Mac OS X is that it qualifies as both a platform and a specific piece of software depending on context:

> My application runs **on** Mac OS X.
>
> To delete a file **in** Mac OS X...

So the correct answer is that it depends on the specific usage. [David Schwartz's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56475/6006) provides a good rule of thumb for determining which usage is correct in a given scenario.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59843/using-on-vs-in

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Yep, pretty much the same thing I noted here. That question was closed, unfortunately. :P