# Using "on" vs. "in"?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

Consider the following sentence:

> I am developing an application to be installed on Android.

And this:

> This has been a major flaw in Android...

To be clear I am unsure of the usage of "in" vs. "on". When should I use "in" and when to use "on"?

Comment: This question is way too broad. But if you limit it to the two particular examples, the answer is: just memorize it. That's how native speakers learn it as well. A flaw is *in* something. Applications are installed *on* platforms.

Comment: I think a simple analogy is _butter on bread_ and _hole in bread_. You never say _I'm spreading butter in bread._ even if the butter melts and gets in the bread. And would there be a hole on the bread? Perhaps, there's a hole in the butter that's on the bread. `software/platform = butter/bread. defect/program = hole/bread.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install software **on** a platform. Find defects **in** a program.

If you are developing an application to be installed *in* Android, then it's going to be *incorporated into* that software and form part of the platform.

If you find a major flaw *on* Android, you are not talking about Android itself, but something else which is running *on that platform* (and which works well on other platforms).