# "in" or "on" operating system?

Tags: prepositions

I see both "on Windows" and "in Windows" on the Internet. I'm wondering which way is the correct way? Or maybe they have different meanings?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: The question of platforms/OS is specifically already answered here: [Using "on" vs. "in"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59843/using-on-vs-in)

Comment: Related: *[Using “on” vs. “in”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59843)* and *[“On Mac OS X” vs. “in Mac OS X”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56468)*.

Answer (score 7):

I would say *on Windows* because I always imagine the question to that answer as: "On what operating system are you running?"

"*I'm running in Windows*" doesn't sound correct to me. You might find the specific command '*Run*' though, which can be referred to as "*Where is Run in Windows 7?*" (you get lots of hits from googling that!), which is synonymous to "*Where is the Run command in Windows 7?*"

"*I'm running on Windows*" however just rings perfectly, and shortened '*on Windows*'.

Comment: _"On what operating system are you running?"_ This doesn't sound right. It sounds like the operating system is a road or a track that you're physically running on. Wouldn't _"On what operating system are you running it?"_ or _"... running the software?"_ be more correct? Also: _"I'm running the software on Windows."_ and _"I'm running Windows [on the computer]."_ (the OS is also a type of software)